# Navigating to the same page but with different URL queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component called `List` which has another component in it called `Places` that displays different places by passing the data after fetching from the URL as props to the `Places` components, I have the url which takes queries as `destination`, `min`, `max` and `type`, I have created a `handleType` method inside the `Link` component of `react-router-dom` which is inside the `swiper-container` div, after clicking on an icon the `handleType` method should take the type and reFetch the data and display the data only accroding to the type, but when I'm doinf this I'm getting an
`error message that says "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destination')"`.
Why is this happeing ? even though I have given a default value for `destination` in the URL.

I'm kinda new to React.js ,3 months new, so I hope you could help me with this

```
import NavBar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar";
import Header from "../../components/header/Header";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { DateRange } from "react-date-range";
import SearchItems from "../propertyList/SearchItems";
import Places from "../propertyList/Places";
import {
faBuilding,
faCampground,
faCircleArrowLeft,
faCircleArrowRight,
faFilter,
faHotel,
faHouse,
faSwimmingPool,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from "swiper";
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";
import "swiper/css";

const List = () => {
const location = useLocation();
const [destination, setDestination] = useState(location.state.destination);
const [date, setDate] = useState(location.state.date);
const [openDate, setOpenDate] = useState(false);
const [options, setOptions] = useState(location.state.options);
const [openList, setOpenList] = useState(false);
const [min, setMin] = useState(undefined);
const [max, setMax] = useState();
const [type, setType] = useState(null);

const baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_API_URL;
const { data, loading, error, reFetch } = useFetch(
baseURL + `/hotels?city=${destination || ""}&min=${min || 0}&max=${max || 
999}&type=${type || ""}`
);

const handleClick = () => {
reFetch();
};

const handleType = (categoryType) => {
console.log(categoryType);
setType(categoryType);
reFetch();
}

const categories = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "house",
  icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHouse} />,
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "pool",
  icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSwimmingPool} />,
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "camp",
  icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCampground} />,
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: "apartment",
  icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBuilding} />,
},
{
  id: 5,
  name: "hotel",
  icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHotel} />,
},
];

return (
<div>
  <NavBar />

  <div className="categories">
    <div className="swiper-button-prev">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleArrowLeft} />
    </div>
    <Swiper
      modules={[Navigation]}
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      navigation={{
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      }}
    >
      {categories.map((cat,i) => (
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div className="swiper-container">
        <Link onClick={()=>handleType(cat.name)}>
            <h2>{cat.icon}</h2>
            <span>{cat.name}</span>
        </Link>
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
    <div className="swiper-button-next">
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={faCircleArrowRight}
        style={{ color: "#000000" }}
      />
    </div>
    <Button onClick={() => setOpenList(!openList)}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFilter} />
      <span>Filters</span>
    </Button>
  </div>

  <div className="listContainer">
    <div className="listWrapper">
      {openList && (
        <div className="listSearch">
          <h1 className="lsTitle">Search</h1>
          <div className="lsItem">
            <label>Destination</label>
            <input placeholder={destination} type="text" />
          </div>
          <div className="lsItem">
            <label>Check-in Date</label>
            <span onClick={() => setOpenDate(!openDate)}>{`${format(
              date[0].startDate,
              "MM/dd/yyyy"
            )} to ${format(date[0].endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")}`}</span>
            {openDate && (
              <DateRange
                onChange={(item) => setDate([item.selection])}
                minDate={new Date()}
                ranges={date}
              />
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="lsItem">
            <label>Options</label>
            <div className="lsOptions">
              <div className="lsOptionItem">
                <span className="lsOptionText">
                  Min price <small>per night</small>
                </span>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => setMin(e.target.value)}
                  className="lsOptionInput"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="lsOptionItem">
                <span className="lsOptionText">
                  Max price <small>per night</small>
                </span>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => setMax(e.target.value)}
                  className="lsOptionInput"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="lsOptionItem">
                <span className="lsOptionText">Adult</span>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  min={1}
                  className="lsOptionInput"
                  placeholder={options.adult}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="lsOptionItem">
                <span className="lsOptionText">Children</span>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  min={0}
                  className="lsOptionInput"
                  placeholder={options.children}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="lsOptionItem">
                <span className="lsOptionText">Room</span>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  min={1}
                  className="lsOptionInput"
                  placeholder={options.rooms}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="listResult">
        <Places items={data} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

export default List;
```

This is the useFetch hook to fetch data from the backend :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const useFetch = (url) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    setData(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    setError(error);
  }
  setLoading(false);
};
fetchData();
}, []);
const reFetch = async () => {
setLoading(true);
try {
  const res = await axios.get(url);
  setData(res.data);
} catch (error) {
  setError(error);
}
setLoading(false);
};
return { data, loading, error, reFetch };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Answer (score 0):

`state` is passed as a prop to `Link` like so:

`<Link to="new-path" state={{ some: "value" }} />`

Your `location.state` is `null` because it is never set.

See [React Router docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) for more info.

Comment: I'm getting the location.state from the previuos page, that has a search input

Comment: "The location.state property is a user-supplied State object that is associated with this location. This can be a useful place to store any information you do not want to put in the URL, e.g. session-specific data."

https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location

Comment: If the data is being passed via URL query params, you can use `useSearchParams()`

https://reactrouter.com/en/6.10.0/hooks/use-search-params